# Upload config to Cisco ASA 5505 via copy/paste (No TFTP)

Tags: firewall, cisco, cisco-asa

I copy/pasted the running-config to a .txt file on my directly-attached PC. How do I paste or otherwise upload that config to the ASA?

All resources I've found just talk about using TFTP, but there has to be a way to simply paste it back into the running-config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply paste it in a SSH or Telnet session (or via the web gui in the Tool->Command Line Interface)

[image]

Comment: I assume console session works too?

Comment: Yes, and if some command fail you can do a second pass after in the correct mode. I always used that mode to restore the config, as I always keep my customer config in case of emergency restore

Comment: I knew it was something really simple that no one else on the internet ever asked bc it's elementary lol. Thanks anyway!